# moveit_core headers not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After trying to include moveit in a find_package(), I receive this error.

CMake Error at /home/marco/catkin_ws/devel/share/moveit_core/cmake/moveit_coreConfig.cmake:98 (message):
Project 'moveit_core' specifies
'/home/marco/catkin_ws/src/moveit/src/moveit_core/background_processing/include'
as an include dir, which is not found.  It does neither exist as an
absolute directory nor in
'/home/marco/catkin_ws/src/moveit/src/moveit_core//home/marco/catkin_ws/src/moveit/src/moveit_core/background_processing/include'.
Ask the maintainer 'Sachin Chitta robot.moveit@gmail.com, Ioan Sucan
isucan@gmail.com, Acorn Pooley acorn.pooley@sri.com' to fix it.

Suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191533/moveit_core-headers-not-found/) by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 644 on 2014-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you have moveit in your workspace at some point in the past, and have you removed it since then?

The cmake config files for packages can often be left behind in the build directory of your workspace even after you remove the package from your src directory.

I've found that the easiest fix for this is to remove my build and devel directories and rebuild my workspace from scratch.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-08-29**:
I did attempt to remove the /build /devel folders and I still received that error. Indeed it was in src before. What fixed it was installing the source code of moveit again and compiling with it However, that should be unnecessary so I'll try removing all the source and /devel /build and try again.